# lowpass and high pass filter in C#

Tags: c#, signal-processing, matlab

I need low pass and high pass filter written in c#. I have double arrays for this filter process. I think if I try to convert matlab  Butterworth and Chebyshev algorithms to c#, it would be easier. But I couldn't find the code of butter.m and Chebyshev algorithms on the internet and I don't want to set up matlab and signal processing toolbox into my computer. Could you provide that codes please? Thanks..

Comment: [SO] is not a code writing service. We'll help with you code if your stuck making it work.

Answer (score 21):

[LP and HP filter - Musicdsp.org documentation](https://www.musicdsp.org/en/latest/Filters/38-lp-and-hp-filter.html)

I implemented the filter in semicode above as follows in our sEMG analyzer software and it works great.

```
public class FilterButterworth
{
    /// <summary>
    /// rez amount, from sqrt(2) to ~ 0.1
    /// </summary>
    private readonly float resonance;

    private readonly float frequency;
    private readonly int sampleRate;
    private readonly PassType passType;

    private readonly float c, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2;

    /// <summary>
    /// Array of input values, latest are in front
    /// </summary>
    private float[] inputHistory = new float[2];

    /// <summary>
    /// Array of output values, latest are in front
    /// </summary>
    private float[] outputHistory = new float[3];

    public FilterButterworth(float frequency, int sampleRate, PassType passType, float resonance)
    {
        this.resonance = resonance;
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
        this.passType = passType;

        switch (passType)
        {
            case PassType.Lowpass:
                c = 1.0f / (float)Math.Tan(Math.PI * frequency / sampleRate);
                a1 = 1.0f / (1.0f + resonance * c + c * c);
                a2 = 2f * a1;
                a3 = a1;
                b1 = 2.0f * (1.0f - c * c) * a1;
                b2 = (1.0f - resonance * c + c * c) * a1;
                break;
            case PassType.Highpass:
                c = (float)Math.Tan(Math.PI * frequency / sampleRate);
                a1 = 1.0f / (1.0f + resonance * c + c * c);
                a2 = -2f * a1;
                a3 = a1;
                b1 = 2.0f * (c * c - 1.0f) * a1;
                b2 = (1.0f - resonance * c + c * c) * a1;
                break;
        }
    }

    public enum PassType
    {
        Highpass,
        Lowpass,
    }

    public void Update(float newInput)
    {
        float newOutput = a1 * newInput + a2 * this.inputHistory[0] + a3 * this.inputHistory[1] - b1 * this.outputHistory[0] - b2 * this.outputHistory[1];

        this.inputHistory[1] = this.inputHistory[0];
        this.inputHistory[0] = newInput;

        this.outputHistory[2] = this.outputHistory[1];
        this.outputHistory[1] = this.outputHistory[0];
        this.outputHistory[0] = newOutput;
    }

    public float Value
    {
        get { return this.outputHistory[0]; }
    }
}
```

Note that this filter was created for audio DSP purposes. To create a clean output you need to set the resonance to `sqrt(2)`.

Answer (score 12):

I found this online tool that looks promising: [Interactive Digital Filter Design: Butterworth / Bessel / Chebyshev Filters](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter/trad.html)

You just enter your requirements:

- Filter design: Butterworth / Bessel / Chebyshev
- Filter type: Lowpass / Highpass / Bandpass / Bandstop
- Filter order
- Corner frequency/frequencies

Click submit, and it computes the following information:

- Gains, poles, zeros
- Recurrence relation
- C code implementing the recurrence relation
- Plots of magnitude, phase, impulse and step responses

You can implement a filter in C# directly from the recurrence relation.

If you only need a few constant filters, you're done.  However, if you need to be able to adjust the filter parameters at run time, you will need to do more.  Luckily, the professor provided [the source code for his tool](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/software/mkfilter/), and it should be possible to convert to C#.

Answer (score 2):

here is one it has many modes, HP LP BP peak, and so forth, it is a BiQuad perhaps 2 pole static filter something of that kind, it is a particular filter and has a certain kind of digital result:
https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore/DSP/BiQuad.cs

```
    /*
     * These implementations are based on http://www.earlevel.com/main/2011/01/02/biquad-formulas/
     */

    using System;

    namespace CSCore.DSP
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents a biquad-filter.
        /// </summary>
        public abstract class BiQuad
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The a0 value.
            /// </summary>
            protected double A0;
            /// <summary>
            /// The a1 value.
            /// </summary>
            protected double A1;
            /// <summary>
            /// The a2 value.
            /// </summary>
            protected double A2;
            /// <summary>
            /// The b1 value.
            /// </summary>
            protected double B1;
            /// <summary>
            /// The b2 value.
            /// </summary>
            protected double B2;
            /// <summary>
            /// The q value.
            /// </summary>
            private double _q;
            /// <summary>
            /// The gain value in dB.
            /// </summary>
            private double _gainDB;
            /// <summary>
            /// The z1 value.
            /// </summary>
            protected double Z1;
            /// <summary>
            /// The z2 value.
            /// </summary>
            protected double Z2;

            private double _frequency;

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the frequency.
            /// </summary>
            /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">value;The samplerate has to be bigger than 2 * frequency.</exception>
            public double Frequency
            {
                get { return _frequency; }
                set
                {
                    if (SampleRate < value * 2)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "The samplerate has to be bigger than 2 * frequency.");
                    }
                    _frequency = value;
                    CalculateBiQuadCoefficients();
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets the sample rate.
            /// </summary>
            public int SampleRate { get; private set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// The q value.
            /// </summary>
            public double Q
            {
                get { return _q; }
                set
                {
                    if (value <= 0)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
                    }
                    _q = value;
                    CalculateBiQuadCoefficients();
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the gain value in dB.
            /// </summary>
            public double GainDB
            {
                get { return _gainDB; }
                set
                {
                    _gainDB = value;
                    CalculateBiQuadCoefficients();
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BiQuad"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sampleRate">The sample rate.</param>
            /// <param name="frequency">The frequency.</param>
            /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
            /// sampleRate
            /// or
            /// frequency
            /// or
            /// q
            /// </exception>
            protected BiQuad(int sampleRate, double frequency)
                : this(sampleRate, frequency, 1.0 / Math.Sqrt(2))
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BiQuad"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sampleRate">The sample rate.</param>
            /// <param name="frequency">The frequency.</param>
            /// <param name="q">The q.</param>
            /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
            /// sampleRate
            /// or
            /// frequency
            /// or
            /// q
            /// </exception>
            protected BiQuad(int sampleRate, double frequency, double q)
            {
                if (sampleRate <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("sampleRate");
                if (frequency <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("frequency");
                if (q <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("q");
                SampleRate = sampleRate;
                Frequency = frequency;
                Q = q;
                GainDB = 6;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Processes a single <paramref name="input"/> sample and returns the result.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="input">The input sample to process.</param>
            /// <returns>The result of the processed <paramref name="input"/> sample.</returns>
            public float Process(float input)
            {
                double o = input * A0 + Z1;
                Z1 = input * A1 + Z2 - B1 * o;
                Z2 = input * A2 - B2 * o;
                return (float)o;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Processes multiple <paramref name="input"/> samples.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="input">The input samples to process.</param>
            /// <remarks>The result of the calculation gets stored within the <paramref name="input"/> array.</remarks>
            public void Process(float[] input)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
                {
                    input[i] = Process(input[i]);
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Calculates all coefficients.
            /// </summary>
            protected abstract void CalculateBiQuadCoefficients();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to apply a lowpass-filter to a signal.
        /// </summary>
        public class LowpassFilter : BiQuad
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LowpassFilter"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sampleRate">The sample rate.</param>
            /// <param name="frequency">The filter's corner frequency.</param>
            public LowpassFilter(int sampleRate, double frequency)
                : base(sampleRate, frequency)
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Calculates all coefficients.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void CalculateBiQuadCoefficients()
            {
                double k = Math.Tan(Math.PI * Frequency / SampleRate);
                var norm = 1 / (1 + k / Q + k * k);
                A0 = k * k * norm;
                A1 = 2 * A0;
                A2 = A0;
                B1 = 2 * (k * k - 1) * norm;
                B2 = (1 - k / Q + k * k) * norm;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to apply a highpass-filter to a signal.
        /// </summary>
        public class HighpassFilter : BiQuad
        {
            private int p1;
            private double p2;

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HighpassFilter"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sampleRate">The sample rate.</param>
            /// <param name="frequency">The filter's corner frequency.</param>
            public HighpassFilter(int sampleRate, double frequency) 
                : base(sampleRate, frequency)
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Calculates all coefficients.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void CalculateBiQuadCoefficients()
            {
                double k = Math.Tan(Math.PI * Frequency / SampleRate);
                var norm = 1 / (1 + k / Q + k * k);
                A0 = 1 * norm;
                A1 = -2 * A0;
                A2 = A0;
                B1 = 2 * (k * k - 1) * norm;
                B2 = (1 - k / Q + k * k) * norm;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to apply a bandpass-filter to a signal.
        /// </summary>
        public class BandpassFilter : BiQuad
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BandpassFilter"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sampleRate">The sample rate.</param>
            /// <param name="frequency">The filter's corner frequency.</param>
            public BandpassFilter(int sampleRate, double frequency) 
                : base(sampleRate, frequency)
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Calculates all coefficients.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void CalculateBiQuadCoefficients()
            {
                double k = Math.Tan(Math.PI * Frequency / SampleRate);
                double norm = 1 / (1 + k / Q + k * k);
                A0 = k / Q * norm;
                A1 = 0;
                A2 = -A0;
                B1 = 2 * (k * k - 1) * norm;
                B2 = (1 - k / Q + k * k) * norm;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to apply a notch-filter to a signal.
        /// </summary>
        public class NotchFilter : BiQuad
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="NotchFilter"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sampleRate">The sample rate.</param>
            /// <param name="frequency">The filter's corner frequency.</param>
            public NotchFilter(int sampleRate, double frequency) 
                : base(sampleRate, frequency)
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Calculates all coefficients.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void CalculateBiQuadCoefficients()
            {
                double k = Math.Tan(Math.PI * Frequency / SampleRate);
                double norm = 1 / (1 + k / Q + k * k);
                A0 = (1 + k * k) * norm;
                A1 = 2 * (k * k - 1) * norm;
                A2 = A0;
                B1 = A1;
                B2 = (1 - k / Q + k * k) * norm;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to apply a lowshelf-filter to a signal.
        /// </summary>
        public class LowShelfFilter : BiQuad
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LowShelfFilter"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sampleRate">The sample rate.</param>
            /// <param name="frequency">The filter's corner frequency.</param>
            /// <param name="gainDB">Gain value in dB.</param>
            public LowShelfFilter(int sampleRate, double frequency, double gainDB) 
                : base(sampleRate, frequency)
            {
                GainDB = gainDB;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Calculates all coefficients.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void CalculateBiQuadCoefficients()
            {
                const double sqrt2 = 1.4142135623730951;
                double k = Math.Tan(Math.PI * Frequency / SampleRate);
                double v = Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(GainDB) / 20.0);
                double norm;
                if (GainDB >= 0)
                {    // boost
                    norm = 1 / (1 + sqrt2 * k + k * k);
                    A0 = (1 + Math.Sqrt(2 * v) * k + v * k * k) * norm;
                    A1 = 2 * (v * k * k - 1) * norm;
                    A2 = (1 - Math.Sqrt(2 * v) * k + v * k * k) * norm;
                    B1 = 2 * (k * k - 1) * norm;
                    B2 = (1 - sqrt2 * k + k * k) * norm;
                }
                else
                {    // cut
                    norm = 1 / (1 + Math.Sqrt(2 * v) * k + v * k * k);
                    A0 = (1 + sqrt2 * k + k * k) * norm;
                    A1 = 2 * (k * k - 1) * norm;
                    A2 = (1 - sqrt2 * k + k * k) * norm;
                    B1 = 2 * (v * k * k - 1) * norm;
                    B2 = (1 - Math.Sqrt(2 * v) * k + v * k * k) * norm;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to apply a highshelf-filter to a signal.
        /// </summary>
        public class HighShelfFilter : BiQuad
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HighShelfFilter"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sampleRate">The sample rate.</param>
            /// <param name="frequency">The filter's corner frequency.</param>
            /// <param name="gainDB">Gain value in dB.</param>
            public HighShelfFilter(int sampleRate, double frequency, double gainDB)
                : base(sampleRate, frequency)
            {
                GainDB = gainDB;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Calculates all coefficients.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void CalculateBiQuadCoefficients()
            {
                const double sqrt2 = 1.4142135623730951;
                double k = Math.Tan(Math.PI * Frequency / SampleRate);
                double v = Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(GainDB) / 20.0);
                double norm;
                if (GainDB >= 0)
                {    // boost
                    norm = 1 / (1 + sqrt2 * k + k * k);
                    A0 = (v + Math.Sqrt(2 * v) * k + k * k) * norm;
                    A1 = 2 * (k * k - v) * norm;
                    A2 = (v - Math.Sqrt(2 * v) * k + k * k) * norm;
                    B1 = 2 * (k * k - 1) * norm;
                    B2 = (1 - sqrt2 * k + k * k) * norm;
                }
                else
                {    // cut
                    norm = 1 / (v + Math.Sqrt(2 * v) * k + k * k);
                    A0 = (1 + sqrt2 * k + k * k) * norm;
                    A1 = 2 * (k * k - 1) * norm;
                    A2 = (1 - sqrt2 * k + k * k) * norm;
                    B1 = 2 * (k * k - v) * norm;
                    B2 = (v - Math.Sqrt(2 * v) * k + k * k) * norm;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to apply an peak-filter to a signal.
        /// </summary>
        public class PeakFilter : BiQuad
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the bandwidth.
            /// </summary>
            public double BandWidth
            {
                get { return Q; }
                set
                {
                    if (value <= 0)
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
                    Q = value;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PeakFilter"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sampleRate">The sampleRate of the audio data to process.</param>
            /// <param name="frequency">The center frequency to adjust.</param>
            /// <param name="bandWidth">The bandWidth.</param>
            /// <param name="peakGainDB">The gain value in dB.</param>
            public PeakFilter(int sampleRate, double frequency, double bandWidth, double peakGainDB)
                : base(sampleRate, frequency, bandWidth)
            {
                GainDB = peakGainDB;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Calculates all coefficients.
            /// </summary>
            protected override void CalculateBiQuadCoefficients()
            {
                double norm;
                double v = Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(GainDB) / 20.0);
                double k = Math.Tan(Math.PI * Frequency / SampleRate);
                double q = Q;

                if (GainDB >= 0) //boost
                {
                    norm = 1 / (1 + 1 / q * k + k * k);
                    A0 = (1 + v / q * k + k * k) * norm;
                    A1 = 2 * (k * k - 1) * norm;
                    A2 = (1 - v / q * k + k * k) * norm;
                    B1 = A1;
                    B2 = (1 - 1 / q * k + k * k) * norm;
                }
                else //cut
                {
                    norm = 1 / (1 + v / q * k + k * k);
                    A0 = (1 + 1 / q * k + k * k) * norm;
                    A1 = 2 * (k * k - 1) * norm;
                    A2 = (1 - 1 / q * k + k * k) * norm;
                    B1 = A1;
                    B2 = (1 - v / q * k + k * k) * norm;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html)/[EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Emgu_CV).

They are both open source so you can have the "code" if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. these sites are very useful. But I couldn't find the low pass and high pass filters

Comment: Not with this name. All edge finding algos are high pass and all gaussian and mean and median filters are low pass.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at source code for Butterworth Low Pass filter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344343/low-pass-filter-software) on another stackoverflow question. 
As others point out EmguCV comes with a lot of filters coded efficiently and avalaible out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Here are some c# code examples of a [butterworth](http://www.centerspace.net/iir-filtering-with-butterworth-filters/) and [chebyshev](http://www.centerspace.net/chebyshev-filters-with-nmath/) filter using NMath's fft.