# Low/High-pass filter on an Velocity/Frequency FFT (C#)

Tags: c#, filter, fft

I've been tasked with coming up with code to take a raw FTT (see example) and be able to apply a high/low-pass filter on it, and re-display the results. I know nothing about the math involved, or the input parameters, other than I assume the user of the app would select the cut-off (filter) threshold values...other than that I'm lost in the woods...

What I need is the most-basic algorithm for high and low pass filtering, based on the example below. If anyone has C# code to do it, that would be absolutely ideal.

Pre-filter FFT example:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lowpass and high pass filter in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079526/lowpass-and-high-pass-filter-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please check this: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15902/low-pass-fir-filter

Comment: However, you have to do some maths to find out the normalized cutoff frequency and I hope you have access to some kind of c# math library where you could find convolution method

Comment: Learn the math and then write code...

Comment: Phil - If I had time to commit to the "know nothing to know everything" for this task, I wouldn't be here. I have about a day. I'll check the examples quoted above...thanks.

Comment: A lowpass filter effectively zeros out the amplitude of the FFT samples (your image) above a cutoff (passes only low frequencies). A highpass filter zeros out the FFT samples *below* a cutoff, passing only high frequencies. A bandpass filter zeros frequencies below a lower cutoff and above an upper cutoff, passing only a small band. Since you’re given the FFT samples (which tell you the energy of the signal at each frequency), I’d think you can just zoom the x-axis to a min/max based on user input.